# Rough estimate of test cases

Tags: testing

I'm curious how many test cases others have for a site similar to mine. It's your basic CRUD with business workflow website. 3 user roles, a couple input pages, a couple search pages, a business rule engine, etc.  Maybe 50k lines of .NET code (workflow and persistence altogether). DB with about 10 main tables plus about 100 supporting tables (lookups, logs, etc.).  The main UI for entering data is quite big, around 100 data fields, multiple grids, about 5 action/submit type buttons.

I know this is vague and I'm only hoping for order of magnitude figures. I'm also thinking of basic test cases, not code coverage type cases.  But like if I told you we had 25 test cases I'm sure you'd say way WAY not enough.  So I'm just looking for ballpark figures.

TIA

Comment: You need a total of 420 test cases each having 3 tests. Up vote this and accept Chris Lively's answer as that is the right answer.  ;-)

Comment: I'll give you a +1 because I think it's a topic worth exploring, but if a hiring manager asked this, it means that either a) he doesn't really understand testing, or b) it's a trick question designed to elicit a response containing the phrase "code coverage." I understand being a hungry consultant, but there's really no good integer answer to this type of question.

Comment: I guess no one actually read my post. I'm asking for a ball park figure, not an exact number. Plus I'm asking about basic test cases, not code coverage cases. And if was a client asking you for some reasonable estimate and you couldn't even come up with one, you'd never be called back. Imagine if you were buying a car and the sales guy couldn't even give you a ballpark figure on the cost. You'd go elsewhere.

Answer (score 2):

I would have as many test cases as it takes to ensure a high level of confidence in the system.

The number of tables, rules, lines of code, etc is actually immaterial.

You should have the appropriate unit tests to ensure your domain objects and business rules are firing correctly.  You should have tests to ensure your queries execute appropriately (this is a harder one).

You might even want to have test cases for paths through the software. In other words, click here, get this page, click there, edit a field, save the page, go back...  This type is the most difficult as the tests are usually recorded and have to be rerecorded when the pages change (ie: a field is added or removed).

Generally speaking it's more about *coverage* than number of tests.  You want your tests to cover as much of the applications funcionality as is *feasible*.  Note that I didn't say possible.  You can cover an entire application (100%) with test cases, but for every little change, bug fix, etc you'll have to recode those tests.  This is more desired for a mature app.  For newer apps you don't want to hamstring your developers and QA team that way as they'll spend inordinate amounts of time fixing/changing unit tests...

---

For any system, you could easily spend as much time developing your automated tests as you do the system itself.  In some cases, even more.

As for our group, we tend to have lots of unit tests.  However, for testing paths through the system we only record those once a particular area has moved into a "maintenance" type of mode.  Meaning we expect little change for quite a while in that area and the path test is simply to ensure no one jacked it up.

---

**UPDATE: the comments here led me to the following:**

Going a little further: Let's examine 1 small piece of code:

```
Int32 AddNumbers(Int32 a, Int32 b) {
  return a+b;
}
```

On the face of it you could get away with a single test:

```
Int32 result = AddNumbers(1,2);
Assert.Equals(result, 3);
```

However, that probably isn't enough.  What happens if you do this:

```
Int32 result = AddNumbers(Int32.MaxValue, 1);
Assert.Equals(result, (Int32.MaxValue+1));
```

Now we have a failure.  Here's another one:

```
Int32 result = AddNumbers(Int32.MinValue, -1);
Assert.Equals(result, (Int32.MinValue-1));
```

So, we have an extremely simple method that requires at least 3 tests.  The initial to see if it can give any result, then 2 for bounds checking.  That's 3 tests for essentially 2 lines of code (method definition and the one line computation).

As your code becomes more complex, things get really dicey:

```
Decimal DivideThis(Decimal a, Decimal b) {
  result = Decimal.Divide(a,b);
}
```

This slight change introduces yet another exception condition beyond bounds: DivideByZero.  So now we are up to 4 tests required for 2 lines of code.

Now, let's simplify it a bit:

```
String AppendData(String data, String toAppend) {
  return String.Format("{0}{1}", data, toAppend);
}
```

Our test case here is:

```
String result = AppendData("Hello", "World");
Assert.Equals(result, "HelloWorld");
```

That's just one test case for the code block, with no others really needed.

What does this tell us:  For starters 2 lines of code might cause us to need between 1 and 4 test cases. You mentioned 50k lines... Using that logic, you will need between 50,000 and 200,000 test cases...

Of course, life is rarely so simple.  In those 50k lines of code you have, there are going to be large blocks of code that have very limited inputs.  For example a mortgage interest calculator might take 3 parameters, and return 1 value (the APR).  The code itself might run 100 lines or so (been awhile, just work with me).  The number of test cases for this is going to be determined by edge cases along the lines of making sure you properly handle rounding.

So, let's say it's 5 cases: which brings us to 20 lines of code = 1 case.  Calculating that out your 50k lines might result in 2,500 test cases.  Obviously much smaller than what we expected above.

Finally, I'm going to throw another wrinkle into the mix.  Some test systems can handle inputs and your assertions coming from a data file.  Considering our first one we could have a data file that has a line for each parameter combination we want to test.  In this scenario, we only need 1 test case to cover 3 (or more..) possible conditions.

The test case might look like (pseudo code):

```
read input file.  
parse expected result, parameter 1, parameter 2
run method
assert method result = parsed result
repeat for each line of the file
```

With that capability, we are down to 1 test case per *scenario*.  I would say 1 per method, but the reality is that most methods are rarely standalone and it's entirely possible that numerous methods are implicitly tested through explicit testing of others; therefore not requiring their own individual tests.

---

This leads me to this: It is impossible to determine the right *number* of test cases without a full understanding of your code base.  5 cases that are at the UI level might be enough for complete coverage depending on the complexity of the tests; or it might take thousands.  Therefore it's much better to base it on code coverage.  What percentage of the code, and branching logic, are you testing?

Comment: I agree with most of what you said. I guess my question is, what are others coming up with in terms of # of test cases to provide adequate coverage. So if I said "I did what you said Chris and had 5 test cases" you'd probably say ok, no matter what, that's too low.

Comment: @KaneJeeves: I can't say.  If 5 test cases do 100% coverage then that's the number you need.  It's not about the number of test cases; it's about code coverage.  For that I'd say 70% coverage is good; whereas 80 to 90% is awesome.  While understanding that 100% is probably unobtainable in an actively developed application.

Comment: First of all I appreciate your input. I'll sweeten the deal. Say you're a consultant I'd like to hire to come in and write test cases for the system I've described. I've interviewed 4 others and they've all given me a rough #.  What would yours be? (Oh ya, you're broke and you really need the mulaah)

Comment: @KaneJeeves: lol.  I'd say that anyone stating x number of cases is what you need probably isn't the person you want to hire.  ;)

Comment: @KaneJeeves: see the update.  I think you'll understand why it's futile... and why I'd be the one to get the job.

Comment: You've never been a consultant evidently.  This kind of thing comes up all the time... based on the barest of requirements you're asked to submit an estimate. You WANT to say "hey anyone who'd give you an estimate based on such vague requirements isn't worth it" but being broke and really needing the job you answer "X hours, X dollars".  Thanks though for your input.

Comment: Just saw your update AFTER my last comment. That actually comes close to what I was hoping for, some ballpark figures.

Comment: @KaneJeeves: Actually, I was a consultant (on my own) for 15 years before founding the company I'm at now.  Either way, I wish you well and hope you get the gig (or hire a good person if you're on the other side of the table)

Answer (score 1):

If you ask a car salesman for a rough price of a car and he would give me that price, I wouldn't buy my car there, because he forgot to ask me some important questions. What kind of car do you want? Which extras do you want on the car? etc.

Same for number of test cases .... If a hiring manager would ask me that question I would probably give him the following answer.

#test cases = between #Requirements*2 and #Requirements*infinite (some requirements can lead to bollions of possibilities)

I also would say that based on my experience the number would realistically be #Requirements*5 (is the number I use at the initial phase, for projects with new, changed and omitted functionality)

where the following error margin has to be taken depending on the phase I am making this estimate:

Initiation phase : error margins = 400%
...
Testing phase : error margin = 10%

By the time you start the testing phase, detailed requirements/specs are available, volatillity of requirements is stabilized, creep of requirements is almost zero, etc.

At that time I also will be able to give better estimates ...